# Materialize CSS Footer will not behave as Fixed

Tags: css, django-templates, footer, materialize

I'm using the materialize css framework for teh front end of my Django app. Things have been goign great except one behavior.  I would like the footer to be at the bottom of the screen (not page - I want a fixed footer, not a sticky footer).

I've got my html in the `<header><main><footer>` layout, but maybe I'm missing something?  I've included my base html template.  I'm not quite sure where I've gone wrong or what I should be tweaking at this point!

Please note: I'm using Materialize 1.0 Alpha.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
  <title> See List | app</title>

  <!-- CSS  -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="E:/code/app/app/static/css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
  <link href="E:/code/app/app/static/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
<style>
    .disabled {
        pointer-events: none;
        cursor: default;
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
    .container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
  width: 90%;
}

    table.highlight tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #fffaef !important;
    }

    .row {
    width: 100%;
    }

    th.result td.result {
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: #eee;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    }

    table.striped > tbody > tr.winner{
    background-color: #d0edbd;
    }
    table.striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd).winner{
    background-color: #d5f4c1;
    }

</style>

</head>


<body>
<header>

<ul id="script-dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a class="disabled" href="#">Scripts</a></li>
          <li><a href="/app/run/get_games/">Get</a></li>
          <li><a href="/app/run/add_openers/">Add Opening</a></li>
          <li><a href="/app/run/add_closing/">Add Closing</a></li>
          <li><a href="/app/run/close_games/">Close</a></li>
          <li><a class="disabled" href="/app/run/movement/">Rerun</a></li>
        </ul>
<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav class="deep-purple darken-4" role="navigation">


    <div class="nav-wrapper container"><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo" ><i class="material-icons left">casino</i>
APP
</a>


      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down ">
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="script-dropdown">Scripts<i class="material-icons left">code</i></a></li>

          <li><i class="material-icons left">access_time</i>Sunday, 21 January 2018 18:09 EST</li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
</div>


</header>
<main>
 <div class="container" style="width: 90%; max-width: none;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 valign center-block">
                <h2 class="center-align">Filters Go Here</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
                    <table class="striped responsive-table highlight">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <tr >
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</main>



  <footer class="page-footer teal darken-4">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col l6 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">To the Admin Site</h5>

        </div>
        <div class="col l3 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Lists</h5>
          <ul>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col l3 s12">
        <h5 class="white-text">Scripts</h5>
          <ul>


          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-copyright">
      <div class="container">
      Made by jenni
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

  <!--  Scripts-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="E:/code/app/app/static/js/materialize.js"></script>
  <script src="E:/code/app/app/static/js/init.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown();


          });
</script>
```

Comment: Consider adding the output of your framework (what gets into the browser). To get it, simply right-click in the page and "View source".

Comment: Some of that is sensitive.  I can update some, but the structure fits within teh 3 tags.  Let me see if I can grab a simpler page.

Comment: When I said *"the output"* I didn't mean the entire source. You're still supposed to limit it to a [mcve]. The difference between what I suggested and what you currently have is that it would be verifiable (inspectable) by anyone here and they wouldn't need your framework in order to answer. Don't forget to add the resources from CDN so your issue is reproduced here.

Comment: This is minus 51.5k lines.  I can pull it back further I guess.

Comment: `{% load static %}` and `{% block jscripts %}{% endblock %}` is not valid HTML. It's something your framework compiles into valid HTML. Replace it with whatever it gets parsed into. You can look in the page source and get it from there. Hope I'm being clear.

Comment: I'm aware - I put a second block with the html.  I've pulled that and just removed the template stuff altogether - I was hoping it was a django templating issue but it's really jsut a CSS issue it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few variables in your question, such as the contents of `init.js` or `style.css`. I tried to reproduce your example replacing local links with CDN links and I suppose this is what you're looking for:

```
.page-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This will place your footer at the bottom of the browser viewport, above the rest of the page. That's why you need to accomodate the page with a `padding-bottom` value equal to the footer's height. You want to do this on `window.load` event and also on `window.resize` (as you want body's bottom padding updated each time the footer changes height):

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
  $('body').css({paddingBottom:$('footer').outerHeight() + 'px'})
})
```

This would be all good if it wasn't for responsiveness. You really don't want `position:fixed` elements on mobile devices. The screen is small enough without you covering it with a footer. So let's change the above by wrapping the CSS into a `@media` condition and adding the same condition to the JS as well:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) and (min-height: 500px) {
  .page-footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  $('body').css({paddingBottom: $(window).width() >= 768 && $(window).height() >= 500 ?
      $('footer').outerHeight() + 'px' : 
      '0'
  })
})
```

Working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown();
});
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  $('body').css({paddingBottom: $(window).width() >= 768 && $(window).height() >= 500 ?
      $('footer').outerHeight() + 'px' : 
      '0'
  })
})
```

```css
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
  width: 90%;
}

table.highlight tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #fffaef !important;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
}

th.result td.result {
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: #eee;
  border-left-width: 1px;
}

table.striped>tbody>tr.winner {
  background-color: #d0edbd;
}

table.striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd).winner {
  background-color: #d5f4c1;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (min-height: 500px) {
  .page-footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />

<header>
  <ul id="script-dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a class="disabled" href="#">Scripts</a></li>
    <li><a href="/app/run/get_games/">Get</a></li>
    <li><a href="/app/run/add_openers/">Add Opening</a></li>
    <li><a href="/app/run/add_closing/">Add Closing</a></li>
    <li><a href="/app/run/close_games/">Close</a></li>
    <li><a class="disabled" href="/app/run/movement/">Rerun</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav class="deep-purple darken-4" role="navigation">

      <div class="nav-wrapper container"><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo"><i class="material-icons left">casino</i>
    APP
    </a>


        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down ">
          <li>
            <a href="#"></a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="script-dropdown">Scripts<i class="material-icons left">code</i></a></li>
          <li><i class="material-icons left">access_time</i>Sunday, 21 January 2018 18:09 EST</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="container" style="width: 90%; max-width: none;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 valign center-block">
        <h2 class="center-align">Filters Go Here</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
          <table class="striped responsive-table highlight">
            <thead>
              <tr>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer class="page-footer teal darken-4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col l6 s12">
        <h5 class="white-text">To the Admin Site</h5>

      </div>
      <div class="col l3 s12">
        <h5 class="white-text">Lists</h5>
        <ul>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col l3 s12">
        <h5 class="white-text">Scripts</h5>
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-copyright">
    <div class="container">
      Made by jenni
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Note: In a production environment, you'd want to debounce the execution of any code bound to a `resize` event. More on debouncing in this [excellent article](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) by David Corbacho.

Comment: Thank you! I was having trouble making position: fixed work - bottom: 0 got me there and the rest is SUPER helpful.

I've been building in responsive-ness although the client claims he'll "never use it mobile" but I have a feeling that's a lie and I'd MUCH rather build ahead.